# changing directory in bash script file

Tags: command-line, bash, cd-command

I've spent to much time in the DOS world where cd.. (no space) works.

I tried to do the same in ubuntu by defining a bash file in /usr/local
/bin called "cl.."

its body is

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
```

I have chmod +x on the file.

It doesn't work, ubuntu doesn't complain about command not found.

what did I do wrong?

Comment: It probably works. The current directory is changed within the script but not outside of if. That's expected behaviour.

Comment: Add this to your `~/.bashrc`: `alias cl..='cd ..'`

Comment: @muru: This will not help with OP's wish to have `cd..` as an alias for `cd ..`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster in that case, I'll go one better: `shopt -s autocd`, and then you can run just `..` and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

The unix shell scripts are quite different from DOS bat files in a sense that they are executed as separate processes, not just loading commands into current command prompt, as it is with windows `cmd.exe`

What you really want, is actually bash alias or function.

Both `alias cd..='cd ..'` and `cd..() { cd ..; }` will do the trick, first one defines alias, second a shell function.

In order to make it available in succeeding shells as well, it should be written in to `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` or `.profile` file in your home directory. Which file exactly, depends on your distribution settings, check `man bash`, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/*bashrc` for details.

`man bash` will help you further with available commands.

If you are looking for more user-friendly shell than bash, then I suggest you to look into `zsh` package.

Comment: didn't work, I read somewhere else that ubuntu uses a .profile instead of a .bash_profile. That didn't work either. Modifying the .bashrc file as suggested by Cyrus above worked. Thanks.

Comment: `.bash_aliases` would have been a better choice for this purpose.

Comment: Not even `~/.bash_aliases` IMO. `~/.bash_aliases` AFAIK is used for aliases added by external programs. The correct way to add user-defined aliases IMO is to add them to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @kos: Never heard that. Quoting a comment in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`: "Alias definitions. You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like `~/.bash_aliases`, instead of adding them here directly."

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, I didn't mean that's wrong at all, let me rephrase it: *I'd* put it into `~/.bashrc`, because that way you can keep aliases added by you separated from aliases added by external programs, with the easiness, e.g., of backing them up without keeping broken aliases; `~/.bash_aliases` is perfectly fine as well tough

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson .bash_aliases is not a file processed by bash itsself, but generally just sourced from .bashrc or .bash_profile, and meant for people who have many aliases and want to save them with  `alias >~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: `~/.bash-aliases` is, as far as I know, an Ubuntu-only feature. The normal place for aliases is `~/.bashrc`.